# SQL Alchemy query multiple tables

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a query using SQL alchemy which would otherwise been very simple if  I wasn't using ORM, so I am thinking to myself surely there must be a straightforward way. I have gone through most of the questions on this topic but don't seem to answer my question. I have these two tables

```
class Artisan(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'artisan'
    name = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    skill = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bio = Column(String(300))
    category = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Category.id))
    user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Users.id))
    id_no = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    users = relationship(Users)
```

and

```
class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    building = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    floor = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    house_no = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    telephone = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    kwetu_address = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    lat = Column(String(25))
    lng = Column(String(25))
    artisan = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Artisan.id))
    user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Users.id))
    users = relationship(Users)
```

I would like to filter the Artisans by a category, then filter the addresses by the filtered artisans, and present the results in a way that associates the artisan with respective addresses hopefully getting sqlachemy to do the filtering

The best I can come up with involves two queries and post processing which I feel is very inefficient

```
my_artisans = (session.query(Artisan).filter_by(category=cat_id))
my_addresses = (session.query(Address)
                        .join(Artisan, Artisan.id ==Address.artisan).filter_by(category=cat_id))
return jsonify(artisans =[art.serialize for art in my_artisans], addresses=[add.serialize for add in my_addresses])
```

Thanks

Add on - all related classes

```
import sys
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Float
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = declarative_base()


class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    name = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bio = Column(String(300))
    picture = Column(String(80))


class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    name = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Users.id))
    users = relationship(Users)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return{
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name
        }


class Artisan(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'artisan'
    name = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    skill = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bio = Column(String(300))
    category = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Category.id))
    user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Users.id))
    id_no = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    users = relationship(Users)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return{
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
            'skill': self.skill,
            'category': self.category,
            'bio': self.bio,
            'id_no': self.id_no

        }


class Portfolio(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'portfolio'
    title = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    details = Column(String(300), nullable=False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    artisan = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Artisan.id))
    user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Users.id))
    users = relationship(Users)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return{
            'id': self.id,
            'title': self.title,
            'details': self.details
        }


class Endorsements(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'endorsements'
    title = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    details = Column(String(300), nullable=False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    artisan = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Artisan.id))
    user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Users.id))
    users = relationship(Users)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return{
            'id': self.id,
            'title': self.title,
            'details': self.details
        }


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    building = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    floor = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    house_no = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    telephone = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    kwetu_address = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    lat = Column(String(25))
    lng = Column(String(25))
    artisan = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Artisan.id))
    user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Users.id))
    users = relationship(Users)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return{
            'id': self.id,
            'lat': self.lat,
            'lng': self.lng,
            'kwetu_address': self.kwetu_address,
            'artisan': self.artisan
        }


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mycatalog.db')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: Sound like your relationship ship are not good!! Can you explain well your database structure or give us an ER diagram or a class diagram !! Sound like the first problem is in your database model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gave me what I needed in terms of associating my artisan with respective addresses, though still using two queries

```
my_artisans = (session.query(Artisan).filter_by(category=cat_id))
my_addresses = (session.query(Address)
                        .join(Artisan, Artisan.id ==Address.artisan).filter_by(category=cat_id))
these_addresses = []
for art in my_artisans:
   art_id = art.id
   for add in my_addresses:
       if art_id == add.artisan:
           grouped_address = {"Artisan Id" : art.id, "name" : art.name, "skill" : art.skill, "Lat" : add.lat, "lng" : add.lng}
                these_addresses.append(grouped_address)

    return jsonify({'Addresses': these_addresses })
```